# Setting up proper permissions for laravel app in ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I have a DigitalOcean VPS with ubuntu, I'm fairly new to web apps deployng and I'd like some advice on what would be the best way to properly set permissions on my laravel app folder so I don't have to worry about getting permissions errors.

I know about storage and cache folders and how I should give www-data read and write permissions but is there an easy way to set up all this nicely so I don't have to be changing permissions each time a new folder, file is added?

What does your initial setup looks like after say, cloning a git repository into the /var/www folder of your LEMP stack.

I know there are lots of tutorials on this but I'd like to know the more future-proof, solid way to handle this.

Thanks in advance and I'm open to all advice.

Comment: This is what i do each time i create new laravel project `sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_name`

Comment: isn't this super risky in production?

Comment: yes in production definitely SUPER RISKY but not for localhost